# Why linerenderer is not changing colors at runetime?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The first script is attached to some object for example a cube and draw a circle around the cube :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

[ExecuteAlways]
[RequireComponent(typeof(UnityEngine.LineRenderer))]
public class DrawCircle : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Range(1, 50)] public int segments = 50;
    [Range(1, 500)] public float xRadius = 5;
    [Range(1, 500)] public float yRadius = 5;
    [Range(0.1f, 5)] public float width = 0.1f;
    [Range(0, 100)] public float height = 0;
    public bool controlBothXradiusYradius = false;
    public bool draw = true;

    [SerializeField] private LayerMask targetLayers;
    [SerializeField] private LineRenderer line;

    private void Start()
    {
        if (!line) line = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();

        if (draw)
            CreatePoints();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Physics.CheckSphere(transform.position, xRadius, targetLayers))
        {
            Debug.Log("player detected");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("player NOT detected");
        }
    }

    public void CreatePoints()
    {
        line.enabled = true;
        line.widthMultiplier = width;
        line.useWorldSpace = false;
        line.widthMultiplier = width;
        line.positionCount = segments + 1;

        float x;
        float y;

        var angle = 20f;
        var points = new Vector3[segments + 1];

        for (int i = 0; i < segments + 1; i++)
        {
            x = Mathf.Sin(Mathf.Deg2Rad * angle) * xRadius;
            y = Mathf.Cos(Mathf.Deg2Rad * angle) * yRadius;

            points[i] = new Vector3(x, height, y);

            angle += (380f / segments);
        }

        // it's way more efficient to do this in one go!
        line.SetPositions(points);
    }

#if UNITY_EDITOR
    private float prevXRadius, prevYRadius;
    private int prevSegments;
    private float prevWidth;
    private float prevHeight;

    private void OnValidate()
    {
        // Can't set up our line if the user hasn't connected it yet.
        if (!line) line = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
        if (!line) return;

        if (!draw)
        {
            // instead simply disable the component
            line.enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            // Otherwise re-enable the component
            // This will simply re-use the previously created points
            line.enabled = true;

            if (xRadius != prevXRadius || yRadius != prevYRadius || segments != prevSegments || width != prevWidth || height != prevHeight)
            {
                CreatePoints();

                // Cache our most recently used values.
                prevXRadius = xRadius;
                prevYRadius = yRadius;
                prevSegments = segments;
                prevWidth = width;
                prevHeight = height;
            }

            if (controlBothXradiusYradius)
            {
                yRadius = xRadius;

                CreatePoints();
            }
        }
    }
#endif
}
```

The result is a drawn circle around the cube with the default color in pink :

[image: circle]

The second script is also attached to the same cube with the drawn circle and animate colors to be rotating on the linerenderer circle :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


[RequireComponent(typeof(LineRenderer))]
public class LineRendererColors : MonoBehaviour
{
    public enum AnimationType { None, SingleColorMorph, MultiColorMorph, Shuffle, Shift };
    public AnimationType myAnimationType;
    LineRenderer myLineRenderer;
    public float morphTime = 2;

    void Start()
    {
        myLineRenderer = this.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
        switch (myAnimationType)
        {
            case AnimationType.SingleColorMorph:
                StartCoroutine(RandomSingleColorMorphing(myLineRenderer, morphTime));
                break;
            case AnimationType.MultiColorMorph:
                StartCoroutine(RandomMultiColorMorphing(myLineRenderer, morphTime));
                break;
            case AnimationType.Shuffle:
                StartCoroutine(ShuffleGradient(myLineRenderer, .5f));
                break;
            case AnimationType.Shift:
                StartCoroutine(AnimateLoop(myLineRenderer));
                break;
        }
    }

    void SetSingleColor(LineRenderer lineRendererToChange, Color newColor)
    {
        lineRendererToChange.startColor = newColor;
        lineRendererToChange.endColor = newColor;
    }

    void SetSingleColor2(LineRenderer lineRendererToChange, Color newColor)
    {
        Gradient tempGradient = new Gradient();

        GradientColorKey[] tempColorKeys = new GradientColorKey[2];
        tempColorKeys[0] = new GradientColorKey(newColor, 0);
        tempColorKeys[1] = new GradientColorKey(newColor, 1);

        tempGradient.colorKeys = tempColorKeys;

        lineRendererToChange.colorGradient = tempGradient;
    }

    void SetSingleColor3(LineRenderer lineRendererToChange, Color newColor)
    {
        Gradient tempGradient = lineRendererToChange.colorGradient;

        GradientColorKey[] tempColorKeys = tempGradient.colorKeys;
        for (int i = 0; i < tempColorKeys.Length; i++)
        {
            tempColorKeys[i].color = newColor;
        }

        tempGradient.colorKeys = tempColorKeys;

        lineRendererToChange.colorGradient = tempGradient;
    }

    IEnumerator ShuffleGradient(LineRenderer targetLineRenderer, float waitTime)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            ShuffleGradient(targetLineRenderer);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);
        }
    }

    void ShuffleGradient(LineRenderer targetLineRenderer)
    {
        GradientColorKey[] newColorKeys = targetLineRenderer.colorGradient.colorKeys;
        for (int i = 0; i < newColorKeys.Length; i++)
        {
            Color tempColor = newColorKeys[i].color;
            int randomIndex = Random.Range(0, newColorKeys.Length - 1);
            newColorKeys[i].color = newColorKeys[randomIndex].color;
            newColorKeys[randomIndex].color = tempColor;
        }
        Gradient tempGradient = targetLineRenderer.colorGradient;
        tempGradient.colorKeys = newColorKeys;
        targetLineRenderer.colorGradient = tempGradient;
    }


    IEnumerator RandomMultiColorMorphing(LineRenderer lineRendererToChange, float timeToMorph)
    {
        float time = 0;

        while (true)
        {
            GradientColorKey[] initialColorKeys = lineRendererToChange.colorGradient.colorKeys;
            GradientColorKey[] newColorKeys = GenerateRandomColorKeys(initialColorKeys);
            time = 0;
            while (time < timeToMorph)
            {
                time += Time.deltaTime;
                float progress = time / timeToMorph;
                GradientColorKey[] currentColorKeys = GradientColorKeyLerp(initialColorKeys, newColorKeys, progress);
                Gradient tempGradient = lineRendererToChange.colorGradient;
                tempGradient.colorKeys = currentColorKeys;
                lineRendererToChange.colorGradient = tempGradient;
                yield return null;
            }
            yield return null;
        }
    }

    GradientColorKey[] GradientColorKeyLerp(GradientColorKey[] initialColorKeys, GradientColorKey[] endColorKeys, float progress)
    {
        GradientColorKey[] newColorKeys = new GradientColorKey[initialColorKeys.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < newColorKeys.Length; i++)
        {
            newColorKeys[i].color = Color.Lerp(initialColorKeys[i].color, endColorKeys[i].color, progress);
            newColorKeys[i].time = initialColorKeys[i].time;
        }
        return newColorKeys;
    }

    //assigns new color to each colorkey and uses Time from incomingColorKeys
    GradientColorKey[] GenerateRandomColorKeys(GradientColorKey[] incomingColorKeys)
    {
        GradientColorKey[] newColorKeys = new GradientColorKey[incomingColorKeys.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < newColorKeys.Length; i++)
        {
            newColorKeys[i].color = RandomColor();
            newColorKeys[i].time = incomingColorKeys[i].time;
        }
        return newColorKeys;
    }

    //asumes Single color, 2 colorkeys
    IEnumerator RandomSingleColorMorphing(LineRenderer lineRendererToChange, float timeToMorph)
    {
        float time = 0;
        Color initialColor = lineRendererToChange.colorGradient.colorKeys[0].color;
        //this reduces colorkey amount to 2 just in case.
        SetSingleColor2(lineRendererToChange, initialColor);

        while (true)
        {
            initialColor = lineRendererToChange.colorGradient.colorKeys[0].color;
            Color targetColor = RandomColor();
            time = 0;
            while (time < timeToMorph)
            {
                time += Time.deltaTime;
                float progress = time / timeToMorph;
                Color currentColor = Color.Lerp(initialColor, targetColor, progress);
                SetSingleColor(lineRendererToChange, currentColor);
                yield return null;
            }
            yield return null;
        }
    }

    //Basically Color.Lerp?
    Color ColorLerpMath(Color firstColor, Color secondColor, float progress)
    {
        Vector3 firstRGB = new Vector3(firstColor.r, firstColor.g, firstColor.b);
        Vector3 secondRGB = new Vector3(secondColor.r, secondColor.g, secondColor.b);
        Vector3 difference = secondRGB - firstRGB;
        Vector3 lerpedRGB = firstRGB + (progress * difference);
        return new Color(lerpedRGB.x, lerpedRGB.y, lerpedRGB.z);
    }

    Color RandomColor()
    {
        return new Color(Random.Range(0f, 1f), Random.Range(0f, 1f), Random.Range(0f, 1f));
    }

    //returns the gradient with a copy of the first key for intersection purposes.
    Gradient AddInitialCopy(Gradient incomingGradient)
    {
        List<GradientColorKey> newColorKeys = new List<GradientColorKey>(incomingGradient.colorKeys);
        Color interSectionColor = newColorKeys[0].color;
        newColorKeys.Insert(0, new GradientColorKey(interSectionColor, 0));
        Gradient newInitGradient = new Gradient();
        newInitGradient.colorKeys = newColorKeys.ToArray();
        return newInitGradient;
    }

    //remove first and last keys since they dont shift.
    List<GradientColorKey> RemoveFirstAndLast(Gradient incomingGradient)
    {
        List<GradientColorKey> currentColorKeys = new List<GradientColorKey>(incomingGradient.colorKeys);
        currentColorKeys.RemoveAt(currentColorKeys.Count - 1);
        currentColorKeys.RemoveAt(0);
        return currentColorKeys;
    }

    Color GetIntersectionColor(List<GradientColorKey> incomingKeys, int lowestIndex, int highestIndex)
    {
        Color firstColor = incomingKeys[lowestIndex].color;
        Color lastColor = incomingKeys[highestIndex].color;
        float distance = 1 - (incomingKeys[highestIndex].time - incomingKeys[lowestIndex].time);
        float colorLerpAmount = (1f - incomingKeys[highestIndex].time) / distance; ;
        Color newIntersectionColor = Color.Lerp(lastColor, firstColor, colorLerpAmount);
        return newIntersectionColor;
    }

    //accepts max 7 colors, 1st and last should be at 0 and 1
    IEnumerator AnimateLoop(LineRenderer lineRendererToChange, float movementPerTick = .001f)
    {
        lineRendererToChange.colorGradient = AddInitialCopy(lineRendererToChange.colorGradient);

        while (true)
        {
            List<GradientColorKey> currentColorKeys = RemoveFirstAndLast(lineRendererToChange.colorGradient);
            float highestTime = 0;
            float lowestTime = 1;
            int highestIndex = currentColorKeys.Count - 1;
            int lowestIndex = 0;
            //Move all inner ones.
            for (int i = 0; i < currentColorKeys.Count; i++)
            {
                GradientColorKey tempColorKey = currentColorKeys[i];
                float newTime = tempColorKey.time + movementPerTick;

                if (newTime > 1)
                {
                    newTime = newTime - 1;
                }
                tempColorKey.time = newTime;
                currentColorKeys[i] = tempColorKey;
                if (newTime < lowestTime)
                {
                    lowestTime = newTime;
                    lowestIndex = i;
                }
                if (newTime > highestTime)
                {
                    highestTime = newTime;
                    highestIndex = i;
                }
            }
            Color newIntersectionColor = GetIntersectionColor(currentColorKeys, lowestIndex, highestIndex);
            currentColorKeys.Insert(0, new GradientColorKey(newIntersectionColor, 0));
            currentColorKeys.Add(new GradientColorKey(newIntersectionColor, 1));
            Gradient tempGradient = lineRendererToChange.colorGradient;
            tempGradient.colorKeys = currentColorKeys.ToArray();
            lineRendererToChange.colorGradient = tempGradient;
            yield return null;
        }
    }

    void AssignGradient(LineRenderer targetLineRenderer, Gradient newGradient)
    {
        targetLineRenderer.colorGradient = newGradient;
    }

    void DrawTestLine()
    {
        Vector3 firstPos = new Vector3(-5, 0, 0);
        Vector3 secondPos = new Vector3(5, 0, 0);
        int resolution = 100;
        myLineRenderer.positionCount = resolution;
        myLineRenderer.SetPositions(MakeLine(firstPos, secondPos, 100));
    }

    //makes a line from point A to point B with resolution of size points
    Vector3[] MakeLine(Vector3 initPos, Vector3 endPos, int points)
    {
        Vector3 difference = endPos - initPos;
        Vector3[] newLine = new Vector3[points];
        Vector3 differencePerPoint = difference / (float)(points - 1);
        for (int i = 0; i < points; i++)
        {
            newLine[i] = initPos + (differencePerPoint * i);
        }
        return newLine;
    }

}
```

When i'm running the game i see in the editor that the Color property of the linerenderer is changing in animation but the circle it self stay in the same default pink color and never change :

[image: Colors change but not affecting the drawn circle that stay still in the pink color.]

Comment: There is no material assigned to your line renderer.   That pink is the color when no material is assigned.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the line renderer has no `material`. Add the appropriate material to your line renderer to solve the problem. If you want to add material through the code, you can do the following, but Unity usually makes changes to the shaders in each version, which may make it difficult to find the name of the shader.

```
   if (!lineRenderer.material)
       lineRenderer.material = new Material(Shader.Find("Sprites/Default"));
```

[image]
[image]